# Laravel: Get element of array to display on table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to get the element data of array? Below is my array data of object **Tour**.

Some Tour might not have **tour_attendees** (empty array).

And there will be ONLY TWO records (attendees) for ONE TOUR.

```
#items: array:3 [▼
      0 => {#2115 ▶}
      1 => {#3067 ▶}
      2 => {#2125 ▼
        +"id": 12
        +"schedule_date": "28-11-2021"
        +"created_at": "2021-11-18T00:16:42.000000Z"
        +"updated_at": "2022-01-19T08:29:05.000000Z"
        +"deleted_at": null
        +"tour_attendees": array:2 [▼           // array data that I want to extract 
          0 => {#3077 ▶}                       // attendee #1
          1 => {#3054 ▶}                       // attendee #2
        ]
      }
```

I want to extract the data and put inside the table as below.

```
| No  |    Attendee #1 |     Mobile      |    Attendee #2   |     Mobile      |
|     |                |  (Attendee #1)  |                  |  (Attendee #2)  |
|-----|----------------|-----------------|------------------|-----------------|
|  1  |                |                 |                  |                 |
|  2  |                |                 |                  |                 |
```

**Blade file**

```
@foreach ($tour->tour_attendees as $key => $value)
 <td>
    @if (!empty($tour->tour_attendees))
       @foreach ($tour->tour_attendees as $key => $attendee)
          @if ($key == 0)
             {{ $attendee->name }}
          @endif
       @endforeach
    @endif
  </td>
  <td> attendee #1 mobile</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You only want to get first and second element off tour_attendess or you want to fetch the tour which has tour_attenedes ?

Comment: There will never be more than two attendees per tour, and I just want to load the tour attendees' data in the table

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap your array in collection and take only two records like this:

`collect($your_array)->take(2)->get()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forelse` and `break` on `key === 2`

```
@forelse ($tour->tour_attendees as $key => $attendee)
  @if ($key === 2)
    @break
  @endif
  <td>
     {{ $attendee->name }}
  </td>
  <td> 
     {{ $attendee->mobile }}
  </td>
@empty
  <td> - </td><td> - </td><td> - </td><td> - </td>
@endforelse

@if (count($tour->tour_attendees) === 1)
  <td> - </td><td> - </td>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you want to set data for tour attendees and there will be only two attendee per tour so you can map you data according to your table like this

```
$tours = collect([
    [
        "id" => 12,
        "schedule_date" => "28-11-2021",
        "created_at" => "2021-11-18T00:16:42.000000Z",
        "updated_at" => "2022-01-19T08:29:05.000000Z",
        "deleted_at" => null,
        "tour_attendees" => collect([
            [
                'id' => 1,
                "name" => "john doe",
                "phone" => "123456789"
            ], [
                'id' => 1,
                "name" => "john doe",
                "phone" => "123456789"
            ]
        ])
    ], [
        "id" => 12,
        "schedule_date" => "28-11-2021",
        "created_at" => "2021-11-18T00:16:42.000000Z",
        "updated_at" => "2022-01-19T08:29:05.000000Z",
        "deleted_at" => null,
        "tour_attendees" => collect([])
    ]
]);

$resposne = $tours->map(function ($tour) {

        return [
            "id" => $tour["id"],
            "schedule_date" => $tour["schedule_date"],
            'tour_attendess' => [
                'attendee_one_name' => $tour['tour_attendees'][0]['name'] ?? '',
                'attendee_one_phone' => $tour['tour_attendees'][0]['phone'] ?? '',
                'attendee_two_name' => $tour['tour_attendees'][1]['name'] ?? '',
                'attendee_two_phone' => $tour['tour_attendees'][1]['phone'] ?? '',
            ]
        ];
});

return $resposne;
```

it will return something like this

```
     [
{
"id": 12,
"schedule_date": "28-11-2021",
"tour_attendess": {
"attendee_one_name": "john doe",
"attendee_one_phone": "123456789",
"attendee_two_name": "john doe",
"attendee_two_phone": "123456789"
}
},
{
"id": 13,
"schedule_date": "28-12-2021",
"tour_attendess": {
"attendee_one_name": "",
"attendee_one_phone": "",
"attendee_two_name": "",
"attendee_two_phone": ""
}
}
]
```

Hopefully, it will help you with the result you want!

Answer (score 0):

You can use also the `array_splice()` function:

`$tour_attendees = array_splice($yourArray,0,2);`

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-splice.php